# Rails 6 Postgres Segmentation Fault

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, segmentation-fault

I am seeing the following error in my logs:

```
2022-07-22 03:50:55.262 [upsell_app] [INFO] ﻿/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.4.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/quoting.rb:21: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00007f21af9a52e8
"dt":"2022-07-22 12:50:55.262 UTC"
"level_string":"info"
"message_string":"/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.4.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/quoting.rb:21: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00007f21af9a52e8"
"platform_string":"Syslog"
syslog
"appname_string":"sidekiq-imports"
"facility_string":"user"
"host_string":"app"
"hostname_string":"app"
"source_ip_string":"10.0.5.150"
"version_integer":1
```

I am not sure how to debug it because it happens randomly and only on production. Can. anyone advise?

Comment: It appears to be coming from "sidekiq-imports", but I don't think that's a module of Sidekiq and Sidekiq usually uses Redis, not Postgres.

Comment: Without any code beyond this error, I don't see how anyone could help you.